# how to set different port for searchkick gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick, cloud9

I have run elasticsearch on port 8081 in cloud9.

```
/workspace/elasticsearch-6.1.1/bin $ ./elasticsearch -E http.port=8081
```

I then add 'searchkick' gem in gemfile and then bundle install

I then add searchkick in model as

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchkick
end
```

Then i run the command

```
Book.reindex
```

I get the following error

```
2.3.4 :001 > Book.reindex
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882:in `rescue in block in connect'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
```

It makes sense because it is assuming the elastic search server is running on the default 9200 but i ran it on 8081. How do i tell searchkick gem to connect to 8081 port instead of 9200? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an initializer `config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb`:

```
ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] = 'http://localhost:8081'
```

[More in official doc](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#automatic-failover)